# MS WORD VSTO - How to display a message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsto

While doing some [data binding operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668208.aspx) in a `WORD VSTO AddIn`, if you want to display a success or failure message to the user, how would you do that? For example, in a Winform app we have MessageBox etc.

Comment: You use the Winform namespace and do it the same as a Winform app `MessageBox.Show()`. Didn't you try this?

Comment: @JeremyThompson It worked (thank you). For benefit of other users you may want to convert your comments to an `Answer` - explaining exactly which namespace need to be added - and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: OK cheers for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the System.Windows.Forms namespace (you may need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll) and do it the same as a Winform app:

`using System.Windows.Forms;`

```
private void MsgBox() 
{
 MessageBox.Show("message in vsto");
}
```

If this stops working check:

`officeApp.DisplayAlerts = true;`